# "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized" when updating SQL table from Datagrid (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The ConnectionString property has not been
>   initialized.

This is the error I'm getting when trying to sava DataGrid updates back to the SQL Database. I can populate the DataGrid without problems, but not updating anything. This is the code I have:

App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=**.**.**.**; User Id=**;Password=***; Initial Catalog=****;" name="ConString"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

MainWindow:

```
public MainWindow()

    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    string CmdString = string.Empty;
    SqlCommand cmdE= null;
    SqlDataAdapter sdaE= null;
    DataTable dtE= null;

    public void Fill()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conE = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT * FROM COMPAINES_EXT";
            cmdE = new SqlCommand(CmdString, conE);
            sdaE = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdE);
            dtE = new DataTable("COMPAINES_EXT");
            sdaE.Fill(dtE);
            dataGridE.ItemsSource = dtE.DefaultView;
        }
        dataGridE.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;         
    }


    private void btnLoadE_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Fill();
    }

    private void btnSaveE_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sdaE);
            sdaE.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            sdaE.Update(dtE);
    }
```

The Fill() method works perfectly, so I think the connection to the database is fine... but when I click on the btnSaveE button, the error appears. What am I missing?

Updated btnSave code:

```
private void btnSaveE_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conE = new SqlConnection(ConString))
    {
            CmdString = "SELECT * FROM COMPANIES_EXT";
            cmdE = new SqlCommand(CmdString, conE);
            sdaE = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdE);
            dtE = new DataTable("COMPANIES_EXT");

        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sdaE);
        sdaE.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
        sdaE.Update(dtE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your save button hasnt got access to your SQLconnection variable.. so its not initialized.

Comment: CmdString is initialized when I click the Load button, and that is always before I try to save. Isn't that enought?
How can I give the save button acces to the SQL connection?

Comment: The same way you did in your Fill command, make a connection with your connection string, try and save it, and then you should be done

Comment: @CarbineCoder why would you use the cmdstring to be the connection string when you already have a connection string variable?

Comment: @BugFinder I added "using (SqlConnection conE = new SqlConnection(ConString)) {.....}" but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post the updated code then? because that wouldnt make much sense.

Comment: @BugFinder Added the new btnSave code.

Comment: sdaE will be null in your btnSaveE  ..

Comment: You are right... updated again, and still breaks... I don't think the value on CmdString is correct....

Comment: You're still getting the exact same error?

Comment: With that code is not breaking, but not saving any data.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection conE = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{

}
```

The using command above creates your SqlConnection object only while inside the brackets, after the brackets close your object is dispossed. So basically just create another connection in your save method as most people suggested.

Comment: That's what we are trying with BugFinder, but it's not solving the issue... :\

Comment: Any errors/exceptions popping up? You could also try converting it to a SqlCommand instead of adapter

Answer (score 0):

The InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, or DeleteCommand properties must be set before the Update method of the DataAdapter is called, depending on what changes were made to the data in the DataTable.

The following example demonstrates how to create a SqlDataAdapter and set the MissingSchemaAction to AddWithKey in order to retrieve additional schema information from the database. The SelectCommand, InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and DeleteCommand properties set and their corresponding SqlParameter objects added to the Parameters collection. The method returns a SqlDataAdapter object.

```
public static SqlDataAdapter CreateSqlDataAdapter(SqlConnection connection)
{
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

// Create the commands.
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM CUSTOMERS", connection);
adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " +
    "VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName)", connection);
adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, CompanyName = @CompanyName " +
    "WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID", connection);
adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID", connection);

// Create the parameters.
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", 
    SqlDbType.Char, 5, "CustomerID");
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", 
    SqlDbType.VarChar, 40, "CompanyName");

adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", 
    SqlDbType.Char, 5, "CustomerID");
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", 
    SqlDbType.VarChar, 40, "CompanyName");
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@oldCustomerID", 
    SqlDbType.Char, 5, "CustomerID").SourceVersion = 
    DataRowVersion.Original;

adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", 
    SqlDbType.Char, 5, "CustomerID").SourceVersion = 
    DataRowVersion.Original;

return adapter;
}
```